# Change DataBase using DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, ado.net

I want to output data from DataBase to DataGrid, using ADO.NET.

Can you tell me how to do that?

When I'm writing something in dataGrid it's changing in database. I use WPF, .NET 4.0.

---

Code:

```
class ThemeEditor
{
    private SqlDataAdapter da;
    private DataSet ds;
    private SqlConnection cn;
    public ThemeEditor(DataGrid dg)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        string source = "server=(local); integrated security=SSPI; database=tests";
        string reqest = "SELECT Theme,Stuff FROM Themes";
        cn = new SqlConnection(source);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        ds = new DataSet();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(reqest, cn);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        da.Fill(ds, "Theme");
        dg.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["Theme"].DefaultView;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean it is not changing in the database.  See answer from Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it'll be helpfull!
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307587

or this... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3adacd01-f08f-4059-bbce-bff736a5188e